# Pass basic_string<char16_t> to methodes that only accept wchar_t * and char *

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++11

How to use methods that only accept char * and wchar_t * when you only can get a value stored in a basic_string of char16_t?

For example remove in cstdio.

- The remove function in cstdio only accepts char * and wchar_t *.
- You can't convert a char16_t to a wstring: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert).
- Char can't handle all UTF-16 characters

Comment: Referring to the same table you linked to: convert the UTF-16 into multibyte, and the the multibyte to wide-chars.

Comment: @KerrekSB some data will be lost in the process. When your string contains for example the ґ character. than your output is not "valid" any more.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to transcode the UTF-16 stuck in `std::basic_string<char16_t>` to the proper encoding used by whatever function taking `std::string` or `char const*` as argument. Likewise you'd need to change the encoding when targeting a `wchar_t` based sequence. Of course, with people having thrown out the idea of internally processing characters than encodings it would have been useful to provide suitable facilities to deal with changing between encodings. There are two approaches to deal with encoding/decoding between bytes and characters, i.e., `std::codecvt<...>` and the multi-byte conversions family of functions (e.g., `mbtowc()`.

What transformation is suitable will also depend on the targeted APIs: not all APIs are capable of dealing reasonably with, e.g., UTF-8. The transformation may involve choices of actually supported characters.

Comment: I want to support UTF 16, so when a UTF 16 character is send I want to be able to use that character. wchar_t and char16_t are both able to support UTF-16. Why can’t I convert from and to those types without losing data? wctomb isn’t suitable for this, you will end up with UTF-8 on windows. For example: http://pastebin.com/MVWjxmqm